# Searching ordered and unordered linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list

In a program I'm working on for a final project, I've got to implement search functions for ordered and unordered linked lists. In the assignment, it's made clear that there's an expectation for a search function for each type.

I've worked with linked lists in previous classes, I understand the difference between ordered and unordered, but I hit a wall in trying to figure out what the difference would be in searching them. In my mind, both should iterate through the list until the key value is found and then return it. How should these differ?

Comment: In a sorted list you can stop searching earlier as soon as the value to be found is less/greater than the current node's value. Because the sorting order tells you the value to be found cannot be present beyond that point.

Comment: also for sorted list you can probably use some algorithm like binary search. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm though for linked list you may need to implement additional structures like skip pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In case of order linked list time complexity can be reduced while performing search operation. You can implement [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) for this purpose. But if your linked list need to be a singly linked list strictly then there is no difference other than mentioned by @kaylum in his comment